# After updating grub, my dell inspiran laptop boots but goes blank screen

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, radeon, grubrescue

I was facing a problem with my Radeon graphics card (getting too hot). So I applied the following solution given [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-enable-amd-radeon-dynamic-power.html):

Enable AMD Radeon DPM (Dynamic Power Management):

- To enable DPM in Ubuntu 13.10, you need to open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor (as root)

  `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

And in this file, search for the following line (it's on line 11 on my system):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

After "splash" add a space and then add this:

```
radeon.dpm=1
```

After making the changes, this is how this line should look:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"
```

- Then save the file and run the following command to update grub:

  `sudo update-grub`

Now when I reboot, the laptop boots up to a blank screen and I see nothing. I get the login screen when I press the power button and immediately shuts down.

I do not know the status of the temperature. I am dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should probably try to get back to where you were before the grub update.  To do this, reboot your comptuer and hold the shift key down.  The grub menu will appear, and you can press 'e' to edit the boot entry for Ubuntu.

Scroll down until you find the line that has

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"`

and remove the `radeon.dpm=1`

Press F10 to continue the boot process.  This has temporarily changed your grub, and when you reboot it will go back to what you just edited out.  So, you need to reverse the permanent changes you made:  Edit the grub command file:

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

remove the radeon.dpm=1, save the file, and execute `sudo update-grub`

---

Now that your computer is running you should tackle the heat issue.  There are a couple of tool specifically for laptops to help with this, and the one I have been using is "tlp" - I know there are a few others, but once I found on that works for me, I stopped looking.

"tlp" can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center, and will work out of the box.  It can also be optimized for your computer, [documentation found on the linrunner.de website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

To monitor temperatures, I am using psensor, also found in the Ubuntu Software Center

Following the installation or psensor and tlp, your computer will need to be rebooted

Comment: Thank you Charles Green, I am about to try your suggestion will update the result soon.

Comment: hello Charles Green, I have tried your suggestion but when i press hold shift key grub menu is not appearing, i see boot options screen to choose windows or ubuntu.  Thank you, Please suggest further.

Comment: Thanks for the help Charles Green my ubuntu is back. But the problem of heating remains

Comment: Will add to the answer to modify for heating, now that you are back and running...

Comment: Hello Charles Green, I have installed tlp and started but find no change in temp.  I am coping the result of sensors command on terminal. radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Kindly suggest Thank you.